# read.table, one line matrices, etc

Tags: r

I'm struggling with a presumably simple issue that I cannot fix, possibly for want of the right keywords to look up...

I have the following file (test.data):

```
Th  Ba  Rb  La  Ce  Nd  Sm  Eu
PM  0.0813  6.049   0.5353  0.6139  1.6011  1.1892  0.3865  0.1456
V.MORB  0.333   0.459   0.356   0.261   0.224       0.203   0.189
```

Note that it is tab-separated (not visible on screen, sorry), no trailing tabs, one item less in the first line so it will be parsed as colnames. Also note that there is a missing item (second line, col. "Nd"); it is totally empty in the file (i.e. two successive tabs, nothing in between)

```
> foo<-read.table("test.data",sep="\t")
> foo
           Th    Ba     Rb     La     Ce     Nd     Sm     Eu
PM     0.0813 6.049 0.5353 0.6139 1.6011 1.1892 0.3865 0.1456
V.MORB 0.3330 0.459 0.3560 0.2610 0.2240     NA 0.2030 0.1890
> rownames(foo)
[1] "PM"     "V.MORB"
> colnames(foo)
[1] "Th" "Ba" "Rb" "La" "Ce" "Nd" "Sm" "Eu"
```

Looks good to me.

Now:

```
> y<-c(1,2,3,4)
> plot(x=foo["PM",1:4],y=y)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Why ? Probably, because

```
> foo["PM",1:4]
       Th    Ba     Rb     La
PM 0.0813 6.049 0.5353 0.6139
> y
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

foo and y are clearly two different kind of animals !

Still, I do routinely subset and plot matrices, so what's wrong with foo, and how to cure it?

Thanks

Jeff

update:

```
> str(foo)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Th: num  0.0813 0.333
 $ Ba: num  6.049 0.459
 $ Rb: num  0.535 0.356
 $ La: num  0.614 0.261
 $ Ce: num  1.601 0.224
 $ Nd: num  1.19 0
 $ Sm: num  0.387 0.203
 $ Eu: num  0.146 0.189
```

update to my update (sorry):

```
> plot(x=foo[1,1:4],y=y)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Ok, we know that.

but

```
 > plot(x=foo[1,1:2],y=y[1:2])   
 > plot(x=foo[1:2,1],y=y[1:2])
```

Both work happily. Now I'm lost. Why would foo[1,1:2] and foo[1,1:4] behave differently?

Comment: Just to be certain, do `str(foo)` to see how `foo` is stored.  Maybe it is not what it seems to be.

Comment: It's a data.frame, but you need a vector. Use `unlist(foo["PM", 1:4])`.

Comment: Bryan:             > str(foo)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  8 variables: (...)

Comment: Maybe add the full output of `str` to your original question as an update.

Comment: @Roland: True it works, but I've been using read.table routinely to import and plot csv (I'll dig up a working example if needed) and never had this issue, so what's wrong with my test file?

Comment: @Roland is right, do as he says.

Comment: The full 'reason' is in `?grDevices::xy.coords`.

Comment: It's not related to your test file. `read.table` returns a data.frame. Rows of a data.frame correspond to observational units and columns to variables. Normally you wouldn't plot the variables for one observation like that, so this issue is a bit unusual.

Comment: @jfmoyen You need to get your R terminology correct. That was NOT a matrix. It is a special kind of list called a dataframe. Like a matrix, it does have dimensions, but it is still a list.

Comment: @Roland,BondedDust. Taken together your comments are rather enlightning, thanks. Indeed I was fooled by the apparent similarity between a matrix and a data.frame. However a better mental representation of a data.frame is that is is kind of a list, so the two dimensions do not have the same meaning, unlike in a matrix, and therefore cols and rows cannot be treated in the same way (yes I'm aware that a matrix is a kind of list with proper dim).

Comment: I don't understand you last remark. In R, a matrix is a vector with a dimension attribute, not a kind of list.

Comment: A vector, of course (typed too fast). attributes() is a list.